# Disable default button click effect

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have button created programatically:

```
Button button = new Button();
ImageBrush background = new ImageBrush();
background.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/Image1.png", UriKind.Relative));
button.Background = background; 
button.Click += button_Click;
```

Now i when i click on that button i need to remove the default click effect and add my own image, so that when i click on the button the image which i have added should be displayed.

**EDIT**

The above which had 2 upvotes works but its replacing the background image, but i want both the images to be displayed, onclick only it should add foreground image to my button.

How can i acheive this ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to play with the visual states of a button and you could do it with the help of a style

Just look at the style below

```
<Style x:Key="style_ColorButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Images/ColorClicked.png"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In the style above VisualState "Pressed" Handles your requirement and I have given an Image source there.

Using this style with a button.

```
<Button Height="40" Width="40" BorderThickness="0" Name="btnAcceptCrop" Click="btnAcceptCrop_Click" Style="{StaticResource style_ColorButton}" Background="Black" ForeGround="White"/>
```

setting the style in code

```
btnAcceptCrop.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["style_ColorButton"];
```

Declaring a style in a Page

Below all the namespace declaration in your page

Just make a tag

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

and declare your style inside it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How i can i do it programatically, can you please help me ?

Comment: the style automatically changes the image at the time of button press action, What exactly do you want to be written in code? changing the style? or making one? Please add more code or snaps of your requirement.

Comment: As i have programatically created button, when i click on that i need to indicate the user that he has clicked that button, for that i dont want the default color, i want a image to be shown on top of that, my button has already a background image

Comment: this style would work perfect for your requirement, Just if it to be managed with code then check the edits I made.

Comment: Ok, i am new to windows app developemnt, where do i need to add style ? which you have written

Comment: +1 - managing a style will be better with more buttons. Despite it looks more complicated for the first look.